# How to passing Action value to PartiellView in Asp.Net Mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Products PartiallView table

```
@model IEnumerable<Products.Models.Product>
```

I'am trying (hide) not showing some buttons if user departmentId is not the same as product departmentId

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th> Product type

        </th>

        <th></th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>

            //  I want to hide if current inlogged userDepartmentId is not the same as product departmentId
            // Like @if(@item.ProductDeptId == userDepartmentId) {
            <td>
                <Button class="btn btn-success glyphicon btn-xs glyphicon-plus" onclick="return EditDelete(@(item.ProductId) )">Edit/Delete</Button>&nbsp;

            </td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
```

I tried to write this code in the begining of my partiellView but it is kind of

complicated and geting errors

```
 @model IEnumerable<Products.Models.Product>
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
    @using Products.Models;

    @{

            string user = User.Identity.Name;
         private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        int UserDeptId = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user).Select(d => d.DeptId).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Now  I created Action method in my Home controller

```
public ActionResult GetDeptId()
        {
            string user = User.Identity.Name;

            return View(context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user).Select(d => d.DeptId).SingleOrDefault());

        }
```

So my question is: How can  I pass value of this action in my PartiellView and save it in a variable and use it this variable in my If condition ? Thank you.

// Trying to do as Stephen Vakil idea

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }


    }

public class ProductModelView
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public int UserDepartmentId { get; set; }

    }

 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Lager()
        {
            using (context)
            {
                string user = User.Identity.Name;

                int DeptId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user).Select(d => d.DepartmentId).SingleOrDefault());


                // Here I don't know how to continue ... I try like this
                Product pr = new Product();
                ProductModelView prModel = new ProductModelView();
                prModel.ProductId = pr.ProductId;
                prModel.productName  = pr.productName ;
        prModel.DepartmentId= pr.DepartmentId;
        prModel.UserDepartmentId = DeptId;
                 // And then .. How to return and what to return ????

                return (PartialView("_ProductList",  prModel)); ?? Is this right? Returning prModel ???

            }
```

Comment: Simple way:  Create a ViewModel that is used by this view, and pass in the `Product` array and the current User department Id.  Better way:  Make the user's department ID part of the user principal data in your login method so you don't have to load it each time.

Comment: @stephen.vakil thank you for your response, but I'am new to asp.net and hope you can tell how do you mean in code, becouse this PartiellView has a productmodel and tha'ts why I have productdepartmentId (@item.ProductDeptId ), what I need is this current inlogged UserdepartmentId.

Comment: @stephen.vakil At the bottom I have edited my question trying to do as your idea but not geting to work. Maybe I'am doing Something wrong. Can you please check at the bottom of my code .. I have feeling that something litle to change...or to add. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Vakil certainly has the right idea that the best way to do it is to probably make the department ID part of the user principal data, however the quick and dirty (ie. **this is not best practice**) way to do it is as follows .  In the controller set a ViewData variable to pass to the View as follows.

```js
//Inside Controller returning View
ViewData["deptID"] = "value";  //Fill this value from the DB inside Controller
```

and in the Razor View (at the top of the file) you can set/access it as follows.

```js
@{
    var deptID = "";
    if (ViewData["deptID"] != null)
    {
        deptID = ViewData["deptID"]
    }
  }
```

Now you should be able to do it the way you were trying to do in the question

```html
@if(item.ProductDeptId == deptID) 
{
  <td>
      <Button class="btn btn-success glyphicon btn-xs glyphicon-plus" onclick="return EditDelete(@(item.ProductId) )">Edit/Delete</Button>&nbsp;

  </td>
}
```

Comment: Hi, At the bottom I have edited my question trying to do as Stephen Vakil idea but not geting to work. Maybe I'am doing Something wrong. Can you please check at the bottom of my code .. I have feeling that something litle to change...or to add. Thank you again